# table to xml record c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I need to store on my SQL Server DB many records in the same column and I use XML field for this.On the backend I have code that reads/writes the xml records and inserts the data in a table.The table is of variable size. I have problem in reading the fields from the table and insert them into an xml variable.
What I need to get is :

```
<BigTag>
<SmallTagName1>  something</SmallTagName1>
<SmallTagName2>  thanksForanswering</SmallTagName2>
<SmallTagName3>  youareawesome</SmallTagName3>
</BigTag>
```

The table is:

```
smalltagTable[] = {something,thanksForanswering,youareawesome,....}
```

here is my code:

```
XElement WidgetListE1 = null;

WidgetListE1 = new XElement("BigTag"  );

string smalltagname = "smalltag ";
string smalltagdata;

for(int i=0;i<smalltagTable.Length; i++ )
{
    SmallTagname = "smallTagName " + i;
    smalltagdata = smalltagTable[i];
    WidgetListE1.Add(new XElement(smallTagName.ToString(),SmalltagData.ToString() ));
}

string a2 = WidgetListE1.ToString();
```

The problem is that this code hits the error :

The ' ' character, hexadecimal value 0x20, cannot be included in a name.
on the line :

```
WidgetListE1.Add(new XElement(smallTagName.ToString(),SmalltagData.ToString() ));
```

Comment: This snippet doesn't read data from the database. What *is* the actual question? How to read XML fields from a SQL Server table, or how to construct an XML string from an array of strings?

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: PS SQL Server already has an XML type. The posted XML snippet though  is probably a bad choice because the tag elements are different. Better use the same tag name, ie `smallTagName` and either store the fields ordered (XML preserves order) or add an `order` attribute. Otherwise you'll need different code to read Tag1, Tag2, Tag3 etc

Comment: I edited the question. thanks for the interest

Comment: what I need to do is to read a table that has the info that I need to store and then pass this data into an xml record. Then I will store this record to  SQL Server.

Comment: Can please clear if you are storing data in `sqlserver` then what is the purpose of extracting data to `xml`?

Comment: The error is pretty clear - it doesn't like the space in the tag name. You *can't* have spaces in a tag's name - they wouldn't be different eg from an attribute without a value. In any case, if your *field* is XML, you don't need to construct anything.

Comment: Thanks a lot Panagiotis Kanavos that was the problem!! its working perfectly now!

Answer (score 0):

I post this Just to make sure that the answer appears clearly. Credits go to   Panagiotis Kanavos. The problem was that there was a space in the tag of the xml. instead of being :

```
 <smalltag 1> something </smalltag 1>
```

It should be

```
<smalltag1> something</smalltag1>
```